# Printing not working in certain python functions

Tags: python, numpy, stdout

Here is the code in trouble, should be self-explanatory with the comments:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

A = np.matrix([[1, 1], [2, 0]])
x0 = np.matrix([1, 0]).reshape(2, 1)
thresh = 1e-3

def inv_powerm(A, x0, thresh):
    m0 = x0.flat[abs(x0).argmax()]
    x1 = np.linalg.solve(A, (x0 / m0))
    m1 = x1.flat[abs(x1).argmax()]
    while abs(m1 - m0) > thresh:
        m0 = m1
        x1 = np.linalg.solve(A, (x1 / m1))
        m1 = x1.flat[abs(x1).argmax()]
        print(x1)
        print(m1)
    return m1;

def pmat(m):
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        print(m)
        i = i + 1
    return m

# I can print the matrix
print(A)
# I can print the matrix in pmat()
pmat(A)
# But I cannot print matrices in inv_powerm()
inv_powerm(A, x0, thresh)
```

Comment: can you do a `print(type(m1))` and a `print(type(A))` in the respective functions to get a little bit more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the `print` not work. It is the logic of your code that fails. In `inv_powerm`, the first time `m0 == 1` and `m1 == 1.0`, so `m0 - m1 == 0`. So the `while` test fails. All the code in `while` not executed.

Comment: Indeed, the initial vector has to be changed to make this work. Thanks!